# showing [Object Object] angular

Tags: angular, object, rxjs, angular-material, singleton

When I click modal and the selected row the output of my text box is [Object Object]?

I'm trying to get in my DTO once I click my Object to the other component

[image]

> .Services

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DeliveryReceiptService {
transactionCode: myDTO;
```

> .COMPONENT WITH MY TABLE
> . TS

```
selectedRow(row){
console.log(row)
this.Services.transactionCode = row;
this.dialogRef.close();
```

}

> THE OTHER COMPONENT THAT NEED TO GET THE OBJECT
> .TS

```
get transactionCode() {
  return this.transactionService.transactionCode;
}
```

> .HTML

```
<td>
  <input style="width:200px" class="form-control"
  formControlName="Example" ngModel={{transactionCode}}>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows `[Object Object]` because you are trying to display an object inside a DOM element (any object's `toString()` method will give you that).

You need a string there.

How do you want to display the data?

If you just want to see for testing reasons, change the `this.Services.transactionCode = row` line in `.COMPONENT WITH MY TABLE . TS` with `this.Services.transactionCode = JSON.stringify(row)`.

Comment: I tried but there's an error

Comment: what error does it give you?

Comment: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'myDTO'

Comment: oh, yea, if you do it for testing only, again, you can put this.Services.transactionCode = JSON.stringify(row) as any;

Comment: its working now i see it but how you put speicific column only?

Comment: well I don't know which property you want but you can change the method

get transactionCode() {
  return this.transactionService.transactionCode;
}

to return only the key that you want from that object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245923/discussion-between-ryuuu-and-cristian-florin-calina).

Answer (score 0):

Because `transactionCode` is an Object. Maybe you want the input to hold a value from a property on `transactionCode`, e.g `transactionCode.id`?

You could iterate over objects properties using `| keyvalue` pipe to print each property and its key in template.

But seems like you just want to give `<input>` some value. Are you sure you want the entire object to be value of the input? I mean you could do it, but I doubt your users are proficient in structuring a JSON - doesn't look pretty either.

Comment: Yes, i want to hold a value from a property 'transactionCode.Id' just only specific column